# How to execute python script based on the server of an ssh connection?

Tags: python, ssh, terminal, raspberry-pi

I'm connected to a Raspberry Pi via `ssh`. I'm trying to run a script on the `RPi` but rather than using a `nano editor` on the terminal I want to execute a python script based on my mac (the server of the SSH).

However when typing

```
'sudo python /Users/User/Pythonscript.py'
```

terminal returns

```
'python: can't open file '/Users/User/Pythonscript.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory'
```

And yet this file does exist under that directory.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand nothing. Where is the script? On the server? On the client? What does "I'm trying to run a script on the RPi but rather than using a nano editor on the terminal" means?

Comment: The script I'm trying to run is located on my Mac - which is acting as the server in the SSH relationship I've set up between my Mac and Raspberry Pi.

Currently I'm using the Mac Terminal to talk to the Raspberry Pi and this is where I've written the script using the Nano editor inside the terminal.

Is it possible to create a python file that exists on the Mac that can be executed by the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Wait... Before you wrote that you connect with ssh **to RPi**, so RPi is the server and your mac is the client. Where is the script?

Comment: Ok. Still not sure what do you want, anyway:

`ssh [user@]hostname [command]`

But, sorry if i ask.. why do you want this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if I have properly understood, you have script on your client and want to execute it on Pi from ssh.

1. scp /path/to/script.py user@hostname:/path/to/
2. then add your rsa key to your server. [This perfect guide](https://superuser.com/questions/555799/how-to-setup-rsync-without-password-with-ssh-on-unix-linux#555800) tells you how.
3. Then just write .sh, which get access to your server `ssh user@hostname`, then `cd /path/to` and, finally `python script.py`

Comment: You mean that maybe he's just asking how to copy the script from Mac to Pi and then execute the script on the Pi?? :-O

Comment: I don't know exactly, but probably he tries to run a script on Mac from Pi, so he can do it as I suggested above... But, actually, I haven't completely understood what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

You have a file on your Mac and want to execute it on your Pi. Two things need to be done: First, get the file to the Pi. Second log in to the Pi and run it. Apparently, you managed step two, so I'll address step 1.

The simple solution: [scp](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/scp.1.html), e.g. `scp /Users/User/Pythonscript.py <user>@<ip_of_pi>:<target_dir>`

The solution that might be longer-term more feasible, if you want to develop locally: sshfs. It's available via Homebrew. You mount a directory locally, and anything you change will automatically be reflected on the respective directory on the Pi. Here's a [tutorial how to install and use sshfs](http://www.read-write.fr/blog/blog/2012/02/26/my-guide-for-sshfs/). On first glance, it seems reasonable.

No matter how you get your script to the Pi, you need to find it on the Pi and execute it there.